# Changing the Traffic Lights with If or Switch Statements

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, japplet

I'm in a rut trying to program a traffic lights simulation for my Intro to Programming in Java course. When I run the applet, all three lights are still lit up even though I haven't clicked any of the JButtons yet. When I do, the applet does turn blank momentarily like it's doing something, and if I press GO, the car does move. I'm wondering if I need to reset the colors in the graphics class, or use switch statements (which I'm not really certain how to do) and begin with a color as I've seen in other examples. Is there anything incorrect in my code that's hindering me from getting the results I want? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
 * Class TrafficLights - At the click of a button, change the traffic lights 
 * 
 * @author Mickey Mouse
 * @version JDK 8
 * @course CSCI 1130-01
 * @date 10-2-15
 */
public class TrafficLights extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
    private JButton WAIT, STOP, GO;

    private boolean clickWAIT = false;
    private boolean clickSTOP = false;
    private boolean clickGO = false;

    private int carX = 200;

    /**
     * Called by the browser or applet viewer to inform this JApplet that it
     * has been loaded into the system. It is always called before the first 
     * time that the start method is called.
     */
    public void init()
    {
        setLayout( new FlowLayout()); // changes the layout from BorderLayout to FlowLayout

        WAIT = new JButton ("WAIT"); //adds WAIT label to button
        WAIT.setForeground(Color.yellow); //changes the label to yellow 

        //adds the WAIT JButton to the screen
        add (WAIT); 
        WAIT.addActionListener(this);


        GO = new JButton ("GO"); //adds GO label to button 
        GO.setForeground(Color.green); //changes the label to green

        //adds the button to the screen
        add (GO);
        GO.addActionListener(this);


        STOP = new JButton ("STOP"); //adds STOP label to button 
        STOP.setForeground(Color.red); //changes the label to red 

        //adds STOP JButton to screen 
        add (STOP);
        STOP.addActionListener(this); 


    }



    /**
     * Called by the browser or applet viewer to inform this JApplet that it 
     * should start its execution. It is called after the init method and 
     * each time the JApplet is revisited in a Web page. 
     */
    public void start()
    {
        // provide any code requred to run each time 
        // web page is visited
    }

    /** 
     * Called by the browser or applet viewer to inform this JApplet that
     * it should stop its execution. It is called when the Web page that
     * contains this JApplet has been replaced by another page, and also
     * just before the JApplet is to be destroyed. 
     */
    public void stop()
    {
        // provide any code that needs to be run when page
        // is replaced by another page or before JApplet is destroyed 
    }

    /**
     * Paint method for applet.
     * 
     * @param  g   the Graphics object for this applet
     */
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);

        //declares and retrieves the images from their file locations 
        Image img = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "stoplights.png");
        Image img2 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "car.jpg");

        g.drawImage( img, 50, 100, 300, 350, 0, 0, 5000, 5000, this ); //draws and resizes the stoplights image 
        g.drawImage( img2, carX, 400, 1000, 1000, 0, 0, 5000, 5000, this); //draws and resizes the car image 

        //draw and fill an oval red for the STOP stoplight when STOP is pressed 
        if (clickSTOP == true);
        {
        g.drawOval(63, 112, 30, 30); 
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(63, 112, 30, 30);
        clickSTOP = false;
        }


        //draw and fill an oval yellow for the WAIT stoplight when WAIT is pressed
        if (clickWAIT == true); 
        {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawOval(63, 148, 30, 30);
        g.setColor(Color.orange);
        g.fillOval(63, 148, 30, 30); 
        clickWAIT = false;
        }

        //draw and fill an oval green for the GO stoplight when GO is pressed 
        if (clickGO == true);
        {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawOval(63, 184, 30, 30);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillOval(63, 184, 30, 30); 
        clickGO = false;
        }



    }


     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
       /*
        * Links the JButtons and the graphic sequences to display the lights
        * 
        */
       if(event.getSource() == GO) //display green if GO is clicked 
       {
           clickGO = true;
           carX -=15; 
           repaint();
           }
           if (event.getSource() == WAIT) //display yellow if WAIT is clicked
           {
               clickWAIT = true;
               repaint();
               }
               if (event.getSource() == STOP) //display red if STOP is clicked
               {
                   clickSTOP = true;
                   repaint();
                   }

    } 


    /**
```

Comment: When you change state (from wait to stop for example), you need to reset the other states.  Using a single state variable would be simpler, maybe utilising `enum`s for example

Answer (score 2):

> When I run the applet, all three lights are still lit up even though I haven't clicked any of the JButtons yet

This is because you have a `;` after each of your `if` statements, which is basically short circuiting your logic, so the code following it, is always executed, regardless of the state of the variable...

```
if (clickSTOP == true);
```

So, instead, you should be using something more like

```
if (clickSTOP == true)
{
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(63, 112, 30, 30);
    clickSTOP = false;
}
```

You are also modifying the state of the program from within you `paint` method, this is generally discouraged, as `paint` should just do that, paint the current state.

The better place to change the state is in the `ActionListener`.

Rather then having three state variables, which are generally describing the same thing, you should have a single state variable, so the state can only ever be `go` or `wait` or `stop`, never a combination of all three.

Equally, you could use a `ButtonGroup` and `JToggleButton`s or `JRadioButton`s, this would allow the buttons to carry a certain amount of the information about the state, as only only button could be selected at a time.

Have a look at [How to Use the ButtonGroup Component](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/buttongroup.html) and [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details

> When I do, the applet does turn blank momentarily like it's doing something

This could be caused by the fact that you are loading images from within the `paint` method, but as a general rule, you should avoid overriding `paint` of top level containers like this.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such a thorough answer. I'll try to make the proper adjustments and see how it goes. Again, thank you for responding.